# Combining two lists into a dictionary, why do these keys and values not match up?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```py
movie_dict = {}
for a in prompt_movie_name:
    for b in prompt_movie_score:
        movie_dict[a] = b
        prompt_movie_score.remove(b)
```

list 1 - movies entered:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

list 2 - scores:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

res:

```
{'a': '5', 'b': '2', 'c': '4'}
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify lists you are iterating over. It's also not really clear what your expected result is. Are you hoping for: `movie_dict = dict(zip(prompt_movie_name,prompt_movie_score))` ? or maybe `movie_dict = dict(zip(prompt_movie_name, reversed(prompt_movie_score)))`?

Comment: Hi Mark, the result "a:1, b:2," is what I'm after, but I am also trying to understand why I received the result above so I can better understand loop logic.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're removing score list values in loop, and replacing movie_dict[a] via iterations in 2nd loop. If you notice what was happening:

```
for a in prompt_movie_name:
    for idx,b in enumerate(prompt_movie_score):
        print(idx,b)
        movie_dict[a] = b
        print(f"movie_dict[{a}] = {movie_dict[a]}")
        prompt_movie_score.remove(b)
        print(prompt_movie_score)
print(movie_dict)
```

Output:

```
0 1
movie_dict[a] = 1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
1 3
movie_dict[a] = 3
[2, 4, 5]
2 5
movie_dict[a] = 5
[2, 4]
0 2
movie_dict[b] = 2
[4]
0 4
movie_dict[c] = 4
[]
{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

Instead, you can simply use `zip`:

```
print(dict(zip(prompt_movie_name,prompt_movie_score)))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Is there anything you recommend reading up on that might clarify what's going on here:

```
0 1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
1 3
[2, 4, 5]
2 5
[2, 4]
0 2
[4]
0 4
[]

{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 4}
```

I don't understand why these values are returned. Thank you for the zip tip! I'll use that instead

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clearer. You're basically replacing score by 2nd loop.